# Is there any particular date when math postdoc results are typically announced?

Tags: mathematics, postdocs

The application for math postdoc at United States is the end  of every year. Want to know when it usually releases the results?
Has someone already got an offer or some shortlist notifications?

Comment: It depends on the program. There is no uniform date.

Comment: But many of them never send out reject letter. So it is hard to wait. Do you know what is the appropriate time we should ask them

Comment: maybe phd application timeline can give you an idea. They finalize applications around end of december and reply around mid march.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, this is about half-true.  The [AMS coordinated deadline is Feb 3 2020](http://www.ams.org/profession/employment-services/deadline-coordination/deadline-coordination) and so no programs on that list (which are the vast majority of research universities) will make offers significantly before then; similarly, many departments will make offers with a response date of exactly Feb 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that in math the first round of postdoc offers usually go out shortly after the NSF announces who will be receiving NSF postdocs. This usually happens in late January. After that, offers tend to go out when (or if) previous offers were declined.

Comment: There are usually interviews ("job talks") before offers, no?

Comment: Every postdoc I've received an offer for had at least a phone conversation first, even if the offer came out within the conversation itself.  I wouldn't expect straight offers unless you're a top dog.

Answer (score 6):

Here at U. Michigan, our first round of offers went out in mid-January. As those offers got declined, we have made offers to replace them, trickling out a few at a time. Many of our first round offers have now learned that they received NSF postdocs's somewhere else, so we made several offers following the NSF announcement. Our first offers had a deadline of February 3, in accord with the [uniform deadline](http://www.ams.org/profession/employment-services/deadline-coordination/deadline-coordination). After Feb 3, we will most likely get more declines and make more offers. We aren't sending out rejections because it is possible that this process may go on for a long time, but most likely it will end sometime in February.

Contrary to what other answers say, we started two weeks before the NSF made their announcements, and many of our offers did not involve prior telephone contacts. I think our actions are typical of a large University.

Answer (score 3):

Seems most positions should have a shortlist for interview within this week (probably 1 week before the NSF announcement and 2 weeks before the [Coordinance](http://www.ams.org/profession/employment-services/deadline-coordination/deadline-coordination)). You should send an email to each position you are interested in to ask for the progress. At least half of them will give you a clear answer and for the rest, you should never think about them again.